# APEX Test method mystery: String comparison results look identical but APEX Assertion fails test

Tags: apex

I am not an apex programmer, but have successfully airbrushed the following working apex code to add one extra field (Account Key) into a displayed string. Results look correct in the field on the object layout in UI, so I’m happy with the changes to the code itself.

I edited the first of several similar test methods in the related previously working test class, but it's failing.  The test says the expected and actual strings don’t match, but to my eye, the actual and expected results in the error message DO match.

apex code before edits:

```
global class AccountHierarchyAddressJob implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Schedulable  {
    public PageReference doIt() {
        Database.executeBatch(this, 100);
        return new PageReference('/001');
    }
    
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx)  {
        Database.executeBatch(this, 100);
    }
    public AccountHierarchyAddressJob(ApexPages.StandardSetController sc) {}
    public AccountHierarchyAddressJob(){}
    
    public static String processAccountHierarchy(Id AccountId) {
        List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Name,BillingStreet,BillingCity,BillingState,BillingPostalCode, Multi_Site_License__c  FROM Account WHERE (Id =: AccountId) OR (ParentId =: AccountId) OR (Parent.ParentId =: AccountId) OR (Parent.Parent.ParentId =: AccountId) OR (Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId =: AccountId) OR (Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId =: AccountId) OR (Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId =: AccountId) ];
      List<String> accountLines = new List<String>();
        String formatString = '{0} - {1} {2}, {3} {4}';
        for(Account a : accounts) {
            if(a.Id == AccountId || a.Multi_Site_License__c )
              accountLines.add(String.format(formatString, new List<String> {a.Name, String.isBlank(a.BillingStreet) ? '' : a.BillingStreet, String.isBlank(a.BillingCity) ? '' : a.BillingCity , String.isBlank(a.BillingState) ? '' : a.BillingState, String.IsBlank(a.BillingPostalCode) ? '' : a.BillingPostalCode}));
        }
        return String.join(accountLines, '\n');
    }
    
    
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext ctx) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account]);
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext ctx, List<Account> scope) {
        List<Account> acctsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
        for(Account acc : scope) {
            String address = AccountHierarchyAddressJob.processAccountHierarchy(acc.Id);
            acctsToUpdate.add(new Account(Id=acc.id, Account_Addresses__c = address));
        }
        update acctsToUpdate;
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext ctx){}
}

MADE FOLLOWING EDITS IN ADDITION TO ADDING THE VARIABLE Account_Key__c TO THE SELECT STATEMENT ON WHAT WAS LINE 14 IN SF EDITOR)
  
EDIT 1 TO APEX CODE (WAS LINE 16 IN SF EDITOR)

String formatString = '{0} - {1} {2}, {3} {4}';   
edited to 
String formatString = '{0} (Account Key:  {1})  {2} {3}, {4} {5}';

EDIT 2 TO APEX CODE  (WAS LINE 19 IN SF EDITOR) 

accountLines.add(String.format(formatString, new List<String> {a.Name, String.isBlank(a.BillingStreet) ? '' : a.BillingStreet, String.isBlank(a.BillingCity) ? '' : a.BillingCity , String.isBlank(a.BillingState) ? '' : a.BillingState, String.IsBlank(a.BillingPostalCode) ? '' : a.BillingPostalCode}));
```

EDITED TO:

```
accountLines.add(String.format(formatString, new List<String> {a.Name, String.IsBlank(a.Account_Key__c) ? '' : a.Account_Key__c, String.isBlank(a.BillingStreet) ? ''  : a.BillingStreet, String.isBlank(a.BillingCity) ? '' : a.BillingCity, String.isBlank(a.BillingState) ? '' : a.BillingState, String.IsBlank(a.BillingPostalCode) ? '' : a.BillingPostalCode}));
```

TEST CODE BEFORE EDIT:

```
@isTest
public class AccountHierarchyAddressJob_TEST {
    @testSetup public static void test_setupAccounts() {
        Account par = new Account(Name='Parent',BillingStreet='Street',
                                  BillingCity='City',BillingPostalCode='Zip',
                                  BillingState='State',
                                  Type = 'E-waste Processor');
        insert par;
        Account ch = new Account(Name='Child',BillingStreet='Street',
                                  BillingCity='City',BillingPostalCode='Zip',
                                  BillingState='State',ParentId=par.Id,
                                  Type = 'E-waste Processor');
        insert ch;
    }
    
    @isTest public static void test_processHierarchy() {
        Account ch = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Child' LIMIT 1];
        Test.startTest();
        String res = AccountHierarchyAddressJob.processAccountHierarchy(ch.Id);
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assertEquals('Child - Street City, State Zip', res);
    }
    
    @isTest public static void test_CoverageForBatchables() {
        Test.startTest();
        AccountHierarchyAddressJob myObj = new AccountHierarchyAddressJob();
        myObj.finish(null);
        Database.QueryLocator ql = myObj.start(null);
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assertEquals(ql.getQuery(),Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account]).getQuery());
    }
    
    @isTest public static void test_executeAndUpdate() {
        Test.startTest();
      AccountHierarchyAddressJob myObj = new AccountHierarchyAddressJob();
        Id batchId = Database.executeBatch(myObj);
        Test.stopTest();
        Account ch = [SELECT Id,Account_Addresses__c FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Child' LIMIT 1];
    System.assertEquals('Child - Street City, State Zip', ch.Account_Addresses__c);
    }
    
    @isTest public static void test_executeByCtrl(){
        Test.startTest();
      AccountHierarchyAddressJob myObj = new AccountHierarchyAddressJob();
        PageReference ref = myObj.doIt();
        Test.stopTest();
        Account ch = [SELECT Id,Account_Addresses__c FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Child' LIMIT 1];
    System.assertEquals('Child - Street City, State Zip', ch.Account_Addresses__c);

    }
}
```

TEST CODE EDITS
Only edited the first test,  test_processHierarchy so far,

CHANGING

```
    System.assertEquals('Child - Street City, State Zip', res);
```

TO

```
System.assertEquals('Child (Account Key: ) Street City, State Zip', res);
```

My test fails with following expected and actual results, which look identical to me:

```
System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: Child (Account Key: ) Street City, State Zip, Actual: Child (Account Key: ) Street City, State Zip
```

Thanks for any guidance to get this simple tweak to pass its test so I can deploy to production.

Comment: so, when faced with this problem myself, I copy paste the expected and actual values into a hex editor (expected in line 1, actual in line 2) and see where there is a variance. Typically, it is because of a nbsp character, extra line feed or tab, or use of an em dash instead of hyphen

Comment: ... and your new `formatString` has pairs of spaces in it that e.g. HTML output will merge into one. So your problem may be extra/missing spaces so check those carefully.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but still failing.  Hex editor shows identical values for each character between expected and actual.  Any other suggestions?